# Preventing parent site styling affecting Vue JS component styling

Tags: vue.js, plugins, vuejs2

I'm building a Vue JS plguin with some scoped styling, it works perfectly fine within another website when including it as a component, e.g: `<my-component></my-component>`.

However, the styling that I've added to the component is `scoped` to the component which means it doesn't affect the parent's site styling, however the parent's site styling DOES affect my component's styling, is there a way to prevent this without being super specific with my component's styling and using `!important` for everything?

Answer (score 0):

Scoped styles work by adding a special key to your selectors. So your component would *not* affect *other* components. Parent components still may affect your component styling. And global styles also can intervene.

Well, you have 2 options if you don't want to use `!important`

First, and preferred - use specific BEM naming.
It is really easy to implement by using sass (scss).
e.g.

```css
.mycompoment{
    background:#fff;

    &--body{
        color:#eb0b0;

        &--title{
            font-size:5rem;
        }
    }
    &--footer{
    position:relative;
    }
    //etc
}
```

which would compile to the following css:

```css
.mycompoment {
    background: #fff;
}

.mycompoment--body {
    color: #eb0b0;
}

.mycompoment--body--title {
    font-size: 5rem;
}

.mycompoment--footer {
    position: relative;
}
```

The other option is to increase your selector's specificity.
Try to use more direct descendant selectors. `>`
But still, outer css may still affect the values you don't even think of specifying.
For example `position:absolute; top:-20px;` or box-sizing/display/opacity and many different props your aren't aware of.